# how to show tooltip on combobox when particular text in Entered WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

I want pop/Show tooltip when particular text is entered in combo box

```
 If cmbDatabase.Text.ToUpper = "TRAINING" Then

 Dim tool As New ToolTip()
  tool.Content = "Warning : You are about to log into a training database" &  

  cmbDatabase.tooltip = tool

  tool.IsOpen = True

end if
```

Above code is Showing tooltip but its basic no balloons etc

I have another code which is designed in xaml

But the issue is that I can't show it When particular text is Entered

```
<Window.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="ToolTip">
          <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
          <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                      <Border CornerRadius="7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="5" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" >
                          <Border.Background>
                              <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                  <GradientStop Color="#CF181818" Offset="0"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="#BE1C1C1C" Offset="1"/>
                              </LinearGradientBrush>
                          </Border.Background>
                          <!--<Border.BorderBrush>
                              <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                  <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFF18D" Offset="0.344"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFF4AB" Offset="0.647"/>
                              </LinearGradientBrush>
                          </Border.BorderBrush>-->
                          <Grid>
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.9*" />
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <!--<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/resources/info_icon.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" />-->
                              <TextBlock FontFamily="Tahoma" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="13" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="#5095D6" />
                              <TextBlock FontFamily="Tahoma" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="11" Text="To expediate your process please click here" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" />
                          </Grid>
                      </Border>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
```

The above code shows tooltip on combobox mousehover

Comment: did u try using the Data Trigger . [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583874/wpf-setting-custom-tooltip-using-style-triggers)

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

```
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="You selected 1"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="U selected 2"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Label>Hi,</Label>

        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: i tried but i am new to wpf  still not aware how to use datatriger

Comment: @Dandy could u try to implement the above Xaml . What it do is when some data "1" is here occurs its trigger the property of tootip . In here Binding i have set the soure RelativeSource Self and Path = Text . The content it need to look , when it has the condition it will fire the setter property . [This will help](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF)

Comment: should i paste above code (style tag) in <windows.Resources> ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58954/discussion-between-eldho-and-dandy).